# Subquery and having clause in codeigniter active record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

How will I convert this query into a codeigniter active record? I've already tried having clause using active record but when I used count on having it didn't worked.

```
SELECT *

FROM   schedule

WHERE  `date` >= '2016-08-15' AND 

   `date` <= '2016-08-21' AND

    emp_id IN (SELECT   emp_id

               FROM     schedule

               WHERE    `date` >= '2016-08-15' AND `date` <= '2016-08-21'

               GROUP BY emp_id

               HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT `date) = 7)
```